# How Do I Prevent React-Hook-Form from overriding HTML Input Type Attribute

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-hook-form

so i created a custom input in my nextJs app, now this input is used to collect user password so by default it has the `type="password"` . Now i also included a feature that allows the user to toggle the password visibility from hide to show vice versa.

```
    const togglePasswordVisiblity = (state: 'show' | 'hide') => {
        if (!showIconRef.current || !hideIconRef.current || !inputRef.current) return;

        switch (state) {
            case 'hide':
                inputRef.current.type = 'password';
                showIconRef.current.classList.add(s.active);
                hideIconRef.current.classList.remove(s.active);
                break;
            case 'show':
                inputRef.current.type = 'text';
                showIconRef.current.classList.remove(s.active);
                hideIconRef.current.classList.add(s.active);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

Now i'm using React-Hook-Form to handle my forms and for my form validation. When ever a user is on a SHOW state meaning `type="text"` and they interacter with the input box by changing its value, react-hook-form internally overrides my input HTML type attribute back to password `type="password"` without me being aware.

I have tried catching the react-hook-form onChange function and calling it in my own wrapper function.

```
  const handleOnChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (onChange) {
           // Manually call React-Hook-Form onChange function
            onChange(e)
        }
        // Always hide password visibility when an onChange happends
        togglePasswordVisiblity('hide');
    }
```

Now this works when the values changes but i have now realize that React-Hook-form always overrides my input HTML type attribute even when all the validation passes.

Please i would like to this prevent or disable this feature entirely.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are directly mutating the DOM using the `inputRef`, so React will overwrite your changes on the next render. I've not used "react-hook-form" but can you change the input component's type in React instead of using a ref?

Comment: @DBS Thank you so much, it didn't occur to me at all that that was what was happening.

I changed the input type attribute using a react state and that solved my issue